# SAN certificates with same common name and different SAN entries

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509, tls1.2, pkix

Is it possible to have two different certificates (RSA and DSA) to have the same common name but different SAN entries?

For example:

- certificate1: type RSA `CN=*.example.com` SAN: `*.example.ca, *.example.in`
- certificate2: type DSA `CN=*.example.com` SAN: `*.example.ka, *.example.us`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificates exists independent from each other. This means you can also have certificates which only partly overlap in CN and SAN because the existence of one of these certificates does not affect (and thus not exclude) the existence of the other one.